# Database Connection and Rollback Process

Tags: database, transactions

I wonder a case. I have a project using a database (Oracle and Mssql). My project has a framework that I manage transactions. 
In thread I open a database connection and start a transaction.(In transaction, there are many update and insert queries.) While code is running, somehow connection is closed. Because I have try-catch block, I catch exception and rollback transaction. BUT; if my connection is closed because some reasons, how rollback query can run on database? How can I handle this situation? If I open a new connection and rollback, does it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a term you should know - **ACID compliancy**:

- **Atomicity** is an all-or-none proposition;
- **Consistency** guarantees that a transaction never leaves your database in a half-finished state.
- **Isolation** keeps transactions separated from each other until they’re finished.
- **Durability** guarantees that the database will keep track of pending changes in such a way that the server can recover from an abnormal termination.

**Concerning MySQL**

In order to get this at MySQL, you have to use Transaction Safe Tables (TST). [Advantages](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Table-Types-or-Storage-Engines/What-are-transaction-safe-tables-and-not-transaction-safe-tables-in-MySQL) of Transaction-Safe Tables:

- Safer. Even if MySQL crashes or you get hardware problems, you can get your data back, either by automatic recovery or from a backup + the transaction log.
- You can combine many statements and accept these all in one go with the COMMIT command.
- You can execute ROLLBACK to ignore your changes (if you are not running in auto-commit mode).
- If an update fails, all your changes will be restored.

**Concerning SQL Server**

You should read "[Transaction Behavior On Lost Connection](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/12cd8704-4133-4329-b909-dc9e54ca854e/)" MSDN forum topic. 
To understand better what lays behind MS SQL Server transactions, read a good article "[Locks and Duration of Transactions in MS SQL Server](http://www.manjuke.com/2012/03/locks-and-duration-of-transactions-in.html)"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using any autocommit feature (I think that's enabled by default in some MySQL installations). If you do all your commits "manually", a broken connection will just result in you never committing the transaction and so it won't ever get written.

You cannot reconnect to rollback in most database systems.